# Both question and answer essentially advertise product

Tags: discussion, spam

A couple of days ago I was going through the close vote queue and bumped into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32524771/1870151) about a particular product. It didn't have an answer at that moment and I voted (maybe incorrectly) to close as opinion based. I also downvoted it. Now I decided to check how it went and what I see is that it got the answer from the product owner (he disclosed that openly).

What bothers me now is that it feels like the question was specifically designed to get this answer and together they feel like a thinly disguised ad. What adds to my suspicion is that the [asker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5325088/sachin-nemzat) registered on SO just a few days ago and only asked this one question, while the answerer found it relatively quickly, even though the [main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nemesis) [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nemesiscommerce) that could help find it were created for this question only.

Should I flag it as spam or are my suspicions unfounded and I just leave the question and the answer as is?

Comment: Smells up a storm of course.  It is probably impossible to prove a direct connection between those users, none is visible.  But a service that spikes web media with scripted fake posts is something you can buy for very little money.  With lack of direct proof, just treat it like any other worthless Q+A.  Close-vote first, delete next.

Comment: That particular product appears to have decided that it will use SO for its support: [http://www.nemesis.io/questions](http://www.nemesis.io/questions). It's not looking good at the time of writing, with -4 votes on the only question. Should they get permission from SO to slurp from hereabouts?

Comment: It is OK-ish to use SO as your support platform as long as it is for programming problems with the product, certainly do not use SO as a commercial/advertising platform. I left as comment on the answer pointing out this question. Let's assume for a moment it is all done in good faith. The answerer is not new to SO. In real spam-seeds I normally see only low rep/first-time users. But I agree that a better call was leaving a comment, instead of an answer.

Comment: I can't make any conclusions based on what I see. This will require further investigation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astroturfing

Comment: If it's suspicious, flag or vote and let the moderators sort it out.